# Update user information in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am doing laravel project and there is 'lead' table containing fields `lead_id`,`lead_name`,`email`. There is a option for edit information in my project, When I am trying to edit lead information there may be a case that I don't want to edit the email address. My code is,

**LeadRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'lead_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:lead',
    ]; }
```

I have provided email as a unique so when I am trying to update profile without changing the email address, then it shows me an error message as 'email address has already taken'.

So I tried to apply the laravel validation rule 'Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:' as follows,

```
'email' => 'unique:lead,email_address,'.$lead.'lead_id',
```

But how to provide value of $lead. Showing message as 'undefined variable'.
My controller code is as below,

LeadController.php

```
public function update(LeadRequest $request, $id)
{

    $lead = Lead::findOrFail($id);
    $lead->update($request->all());
    return redirect('lead');
}
```

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Can't you pass the value as a parameter of the `rules` function?

Comment: Post the code of  your update method of your controller

Comment: I have updated the code providing update method of controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your support,
I tried the follwing code in LeadRequest.php and this worked for me,

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'lead_name' => 'required',
        'email' =>  'required|email|unique:lead,email,NULL,id,lead_id,'.Auth::user()->id,]; }
```

You  can refer the link,
http://laravel.io/forum/03-11-2014-validation-unique-to-user

Answer (score 0):

Look at my working example:

```
public function rulesUserEdit($id = NULL)
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'oib' => 'required|min:11|max:11|unique:users' . ($id ? ",oib,$id" : ''),
    ];
}
```

it should work for you. You need to pass user id in argument when user is updating. When user is creating pass NULL, or nothing because NULL is default argument.